# JQuery used $.post, $.get and $.ajax not working for my code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to post and get data from php file using JQuery. I have tried jQueries post, get and the $.ajax method and still no luck. The code does not seem to call the php code.

This is myUpload.php file which calls the test.js file and this works. It looks complicated but all its doing is whenever the user selects myUploads its making a sql query to get all the images from the database and then appends them to a href inside a list after assigning an id and path attribute.

```
$query = mysql_query("Select path, imgID from `images`");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "<li><img src=\"{$row['path']}\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\"/><a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=\"{$row['imgID']}\" path=\"{$row['path']}\"><img src=\"remove.png\" height=\"12px\" width=\"12px\"/></a></li>";
```

This is my JQuery code inside my test.js file, which runs correctly when the user clicks on an a link. I am able to retrieve all the attributes so thats all working fine, its from $.post that the code appears to stop. This is also embedded in a document.ready function and ive used the import statements of JQuery in myUpload.php file

```
$('a').click(function(){
var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var parent = $(this).parent();
var path = $(this).attr('path');
alert(path);
$.post('delete.php', {id:del_id},function(data){
alert(path);
parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
});
});​
```

My delete.php file at the  minute has only got

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

For testing purposes I have also included the echo on its own eg. echo "anything";, and as this didn't run I know that the delete.php file isn't getting called.

I also tried Ajax method by replacing the code listed under text.js with this:

```
                    $('a').click(function()
         {

        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var path = $(this).attr('path');
        //alert(path);
        $.ajax({
         type:"post",
        url:"delete.php",                       
                    data:"path="+path+"&del_id="+del_id,                                         
                    success:function(data){         
                   parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
               });
     });​
```

The slideUp feature works but again the code in delete.php does not run.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Ps I am new to php and JQuery. Thanks

Comment: Check your URL request (network tab), is it accurate?

Comment: If you don't already, use Firebug for Firefox to track your JavaScripts. It will output any error you might have.

Comment: What is your current url? Maybe "delete.php" should be "\delete.php".

Comment: surely this seems to be a path issue for `delete.php`, it seems now that you have your js code somewhere else and your php is somewhere else, but in your code you are referencing at same level where you have your js code.

Answer (score 0):

**Use just check connection.**

```
//Your Code
$query = mysql_query("Select path, imgID from `images`");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "<li><img src=\"{$row['path']}\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\"/><a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=\"{$row['imgID']}\" path=\"{$row['path']}\"><img src=\"remove.png\" height=\"12px\" width=\"12px\"/></a></li>";

//My Code

    define('DB_NAME', 'Databasename');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$query = @mysqli_query($con,"SELECT path, imgID FROM images");
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<li><img src=\"{$row['path']}\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\"/><a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=\"{$row['imgID']}\" path=\"{$row['path']}\"><img src=\"remove.png\" height=\"12px\" width=\"12px\"/></a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```